# Pythonic way to return dict entry from list with specific key-value pair?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I'm trying to process a JSON file. Contained within the file is an list of `links` like this:

```
"links": [
    {
        "href": "https://specificURL/incidents",
        "rel": "canonical"
    },
    {
        "href": "https://specificURL/metadata-catalog/incidents",
        "mediaType": "application/schema+json",
        "rel": "describedby"
    },
    {
        "href": "https://specificURL/incidents?limit=10&fromId=11",
        "rel": "next"
    },
    {
        "href": "https://specificURL/incidents-search-form",
        "rel": "search-form"
    },
    {
        "href": "https://specificURL/incidents?limit=10",
        "rel": "self"
    }
]
```

I'm pulling the next link by looping through the list, but I'm curious if there's a more "pythonic" way to do so.

Working code:

```
for link in responseData['links']:
    if link['rel'] == "next":
        print(link['href'])
```

Is this really the most pythonic way to do this?

Comment: This code is Pythonic. If you wanted to create a list, you might use a list-comprehension, but for-loops are *perfectly pythonic*. As an aside, this is not an array, this is a `list`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could reorganize the data structure to index each entry by `rel`. It would provide a more natural way to access the entries at the cost of having to do a transformation pass.

```
hrefs_by_rel = {link['rel']: link['href'] for link in responseData['links']}
print(hrefs_by_rel['next'])
```

(It would also cause duplicate entries to be discarded.)

You *could* change the explicit loop into a list comprehension, though I wouldn't necessarily consider it better style.

```
rel_hrefs = [link['href'] for link in responseData['links'] if link['rel'] == "next"]
```